# Docker postgres 9.4 password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running very basic `docker-compose` with following **`docker-compose.yml`** and getting following error.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
  vote:
    image: voting-app
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - redis
  worker:
    image: worker-app
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
  result:
    image: result-app
    ports:
      - 5001:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
```

Error generated,

```
db_1      | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
db_1      | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
db_1      | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
db_1      | syncing data to disk ...
db_1      | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1      | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1      | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1      | ok
db_1      |
db_1      | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1      |
db_1      |     postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
db_1      | or
db_1      |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1      |
db_1      | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-03 12:45:13 UTC
db_1      | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1      | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1      | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
worker_1  | Waiting for db
result_1  | Waiting for db
db_1      |  done
db_1      | server started
db_1      | CREATE DATABASE
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1      |
db_1      | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1      | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1      | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1      | waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  shutting down
db_1      | LOG:  database system is shut down
worker_1  | Waiting for db
result_1  | Waiting for db
db_1      |  done
db_1      | server stopped
db_1      |
db_1      | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1      |
db_1      | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-03 12:45:15 UTC
db_1      | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1      | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1      | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1      | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1      | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
db_1      | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1      | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

I checked on various stackoverflow existing questions but none of them are rectifying actual issue. Some suggesting to run postgres docker and bash it to update the password but its a workaround. Anyone has any concrete solution to this?

Comment: If you create the database with user `udcoker`, I wouldn't be surprised if there is no user `postgres`. At any rate, consult the PostgreSQL log files.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe expected behavior is to not use ```postgres``` as a user. But somehow this user is picked up when docker-compose up is ran.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally and would be good to share what `mistake` I had done.

I changed the database configuration by providing `environment` variable in the `docker-compose.yml` file in db service as mentioned in the question already,

```
environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=udcoker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
```

But the same needs to be updated in all the other custom services (open source github) which are trying to connect to this `depende-on` postgres database with same user/password/database which was not done.

However the error given by docker-compose is not explaining the situation clearly.

In All, I updated the applications with above username/password/database in connection property and the containers are up.